# Fiber integration is independent of the operations involved.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

In [Definition 2 of Fiber Integration nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+integration#in_generalized_cohomology_via_pontryaginthom_collapse_maps) post, the author claimed that

> the operation is independent of the choices involved.

How is this so?

The post itself is quite long. I think it is easier for one to read it directly from the site.